# RabbitMQ not starting and showing below error msg

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

The RabbitMQ service is starting.
The RabbitMQ service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: you should post also the rabbitmq logs

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred on my machine. I followed the following steps.
1. Uninstall RabbitMQ
2. Update the Windows OS
3. Install RabbitMQ
4. Start RabbitMQ